# Загрузка json файла с сервера по URL

Tags: javascript, json

Я пытаюсь загрузить **JSON файл** с сервера по **URL** адресу и пропарсить его. Мне это не удаётся, потому что вместо файла я получаю тип данных (т.е. **object**).

Код:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var data;
        $.getJSON("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", " ", function (data) {
            console.log(data + "@document ready");
            var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data); 
            console.log(parsedJson);
        });
    });
```

Вывод:

```
[object Object]@document ready
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Object.success (c:\Users\user\source\repos\WebSite1\script.js:19:32)
        at u (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:27457)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:28202)
        at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:77651)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:79907)
```

Поправка:
Создал тестовый проект, код из HtmlPage.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Test.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Код из Test.js:

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var data;
    $.getJSON("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", " ", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data); 
        //console.log(parsedJson);
    });
});
```

Вывод при исполнении:

```
output
```

Comment: Так jQuery уже вызвал JSON.parse автоматически за вас, вам не нужно это делать второй раз

Comment: Проблема в том, что при выводе данных он выводит тип данных вместо содержимого файла

Comment: Ну так вы выведите по-нормальному console.log(data)

Comment: Сделал console.log(data), вывело: output

Comment: Если тип object, то оно совершенно никак не может вывести просто output, вы где-то нас обманываете

Comment: Ваш текущий код целиком и полностью рабочий, выводит все данные и никакого "output" среди этих данных нет. Проверил в Firefox и Chrome — работает ([мой скриншот из Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LstxP.png)). Покажите ваш нерабочий скриншот со словом "output", а то мне всё ещё приходится считать, что вы нас обманываете

Comment: Ахах, я пользовался консолью вывода у Visual Studio, она показывала мне https://imgur.com/tIEmROn

Comment: Консоль в хроме вывела https://imgur.com/dnIk4Mv

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться